# Resource scheduling platform supporting exact cover? (e.g. HOWTO maximize room usage)

Tags: web-apps, cross-platform, calendar, scheduling, resource-management

Is there a platform similar to Doodle or Google Calendar that supports scheduling resources to different parties? Let's say I have two rooms available for meetings of 1 hours. I can use these rooms for only one day next month, so to maximize my resources, I ask 40 students in class to tell me their availabilities in that day. Then, I'll maximize my room usage (less time for empty room without appointments is better) based on their availability, meeting with those scheduled students only once each.

So this is a exact cover problem, and is actually very universal. Is there a platform that provides this? I don't think Doodle can do that. One possibility is to collect everyone's data through Google Sheet then run my house-built exact cover program using DLX (Dancing Links), but a nice interface like Doodle would be something people prefer to interact with.

Answer (score 1):

There is [Optaplanner](https://www.optaplanner.org/) [workbench](https://github.com/kiegroup) which is a platform for solving planning problems. There is this [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/bpBGujiMCAs) that demonstrates solving a similar problem but with courses also as a constraint but you should be able to customize this using the platform.

Comment: It seems awfully complicated; there doesn't seem to be any convenient way to schedule a project with others that are spread over sessions (in time and space), where convenience means others do not need to sign up for new service or learn anything new (Google Calendar is blatantly simple in that). I would prefer sending them a shared Google Sheet link, getting their availability, then using an DLX solver locally.